# Solr wildcard syntax only working at end of searched text?

Tags: solr, schema, wildcard

I've implemented a Solr 7.6 index and populated it.  My first schema is simple...

```
{
"add-field": [{
    "name": "name",
    "type": "text_en",
    "indexed": true,
    "stored": true
}, {
    "name": "description",
    "type": "text_en",
    "indexed": true,
    "stored": true
}, {
    "name": "datafile-meta",
    "type": "text_en",
    "indexed": true,
    "stored": false
}, {
    "name": "datafile-content",
    "type": "text_en",
    "indexed": true,
    "stored": false
}]
}
```

I added a couple of hundred documents knowing that two contain the word "pineapple".

I then proceeded to test queries...

```
((name:pineapple)OR(description:pineapple)OR(datafile-meta:pineapple)OR(datafile-content:pineapple))
```

hits=2 status=0 QTime=0

```
((name:pine*)OR(description:pine*)OR(datafile-meta:pine*)OR(datafile-content:pine*))
```

hits=2 status=0 QTime=1

```
((name:*apple)OR(description:*apple)OR(datafile-meta:*apple)OR(datafile-content:*apple))
```

hits=0 status=0 QTime=3

```
((name:p*ple)OR(description:p*ple)OR(datafile-meta:p*ple)OR(datafile-content:p*ple))
```

hits=0 status=0 QTime=3

```
((name:p?????ple)OR(description:p?????ple)OR(datafile-meta:p?????ple)OR(datafile-content:p?????ple))
```

hits=0 status=0 QTime=2

So only `pineapple` and `pine*` returned hits.  I don't understand why the other wildcard combinations: `*apple`, `p*ple`, and `p?????ple`, returned zero.

Have I chosen the wrong field type?

Answer (score 0):

From what you are trying to do with wildcards, I assume that you chose the wrong type. You are searching for character fragments of words, this usually done with [ngrams](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/tokenizers.html#Tokenizers-N-GramTokenizer).

To your question, why this does not hit. Solr does not analyze text as soon as a wildcard (`*`, `?`) appears in it. But as your field uses an analyzed type, the indexed content does not match the queried content. You can use the [Analysis Screen](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/analysis-screen.html) of your Solr instance to check this.

As a general rule of thumb, when you start using wildcards, you are doing something that can be done better employing the right tokenizers and filters. When you like using wildcards, you still think in patterns that originate from non-indexed systems - e.g. like queries in a SQL database. Within the systems I developed so far, we started to strip wildcards from user input quite soon and replaced them with blanks, to avoid this collusion.

Comment: .. and in this particular case it's probably the stemming filter that's attached to the `text_en` type that breaks it - the apple ending is probably stored as appl or something like that internally, so `*apple` doesn't match any tokens.